# Why do these tests fail after I build OpenSSL 1.1.1d using Visual Studio Native Tool x86?

Tags: windows, perl, openssl, nmake

I'm tring to compile OpenSSL with Visual Studio 2017, I'm using Native Tool x86 to do that.

I have installed:

1. StawberryPerl 5.30.1001
2. NASM 2.14.02

I have already added these directories to `%PATH%` environment variable:

1. `C:\Strawberry\c\bin`
2. `C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin`
3. `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin`
4. `C:\Program Files\NASM`

I use these comands:

1. `perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix="C:\<some-path>\bin" --openssldir="C:\<some-path>\ssl"`
2. `nmake`
3. `nmake test`
4. `nmake install`
5. `nmake clean`

During the test run, I always receive these errors:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe' : codice restituito '0x1'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : codice restituito '0x2'
```

This is the full output from `nmake test`:

```
        Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility   versione 14.16.27035.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.

            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" /                   depend && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe" /                   _tests

    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility   versione 14.16.27035.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.


    Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility   versione 14.16.27035.0
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.

            mkdir .\test\test-runs
            set SRCTOP=.
            set BLDTOP=.
            set RESULT_D=.\test\test-runs
            set PERL=C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
            set OPENSSL_ENGINES=C:\Users\Giacomo Bertozzi\Desktop\openssl-1.1.1d\engines
            set OPENSSL_DEBUG_MEMORY=on
            "C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" ".\test\run_tests.pl"
    test\recipes\01-test_abort.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\01-test_sanity.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\01-test_symbol_presence.t .......... ok
    test\recipes\01-test_test.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\02-test_errstr.t ................... skipped: This is unsupported on MSYS/MinGW or MSWin32
    test\recipes\02-test_internal_ctype.t ........... ok
    test\recipes\02-test_lhash.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\02-test_ordinals.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\02-test_stack.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\03-test_exdata.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_asn1.t ............ ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_chacha.t .......... ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_curve448.t ........ ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_ec.t .............. ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_mdc2.t ............ ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_modes.t ........... ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_poly1305.t ........ ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_siphash.t ......... ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_sm2.t ............. ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_sm4.t ............. ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_ssl_cert_table.t .. ok
    test\recipes\03-test_internal_x509.t ............ ok
    test\recipes\03-test_ui.t ....................... ok
    test\recipes\04-test_asn1_decode.t .............. ok
    test\recipes\04-test_asn1_encode.t .............. ok
    test\recipes\04-test_asn1_string_table.t ........ ok
    test\recipes\04-test_bio_callback.t ............. ok
    test\recipes\04-test_bioprint.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\04-test_err.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\04-test_pem.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_bf.t ....................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_cast.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_des.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_hmac.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_idea.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_md2.t ...................... skipped: md2 is not supported by this OpenSSL build
    test\recipes\05-test_mdc2.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_rand.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_rc2.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_rc4.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\05-test_rc5.t ...................... skipped: rc5 is not supported by this OpenSSL build
    test\recipes\06-test-rdrand.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\10-test_bn.t ....................... ok
    test\recipes\10-test_exp.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_dh.t ....................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_dsa.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_ec.t ....................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_ecdsa.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_ecparam.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\15-test_genrsa.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_mp_rsa.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_out_option.t ............... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_rsa.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\15-test_rsapss.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\20-test_enc.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\20-test_enc_more.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\20-test_passwd.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\25-test_crl.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\25-test_d2i.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\25-test_pkcs7.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\25-test_req.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\25-test_sid.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\25-test_verify.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\25-test_x509.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\30-test_afalg.t .................... skipped: test_afalg not supported for this build
    test\recipes\30-test_engine.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\30-test_evp.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\30-test_evp_extra.t ................ ok
    test\recipes\30-test_pbelu.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\30-test_pkey_meth.t ................ ok
    test\recipes\30-test_pkey_meth_kdf.t ............ ok
    test\recipes\40-test_rehash.t ................... skipped: test_rehash is not available on this platform
    test\recipes\60-test_x509_check_cert_pkey.t ..... ok
    test\recipes\60-test_x509_dup_cert.t ............ ok
    test\recipes\60-test_x509_store.t ............... skipped: test_rehash is not available on this platform
    test\recipes\60-test_x509_time.t ................ ok
    test\recipes\70-test_asyncio.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\70-test_bad_dtls.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\70-test_clienthello.t .............. ok
    test\recipes\70-test_comp.t ..................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_key_share.t ................ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_packet.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\70-test_recordlen.t ................ ok
    test\recipes\70-test_renegotiation.t ............ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_servername.t ............... ok
    test\recipes\70-test_sslcbcpadding.t ............ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslcertstatus.t ............ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslextension.t ............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslmessages.t .............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslrecords.t ............... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslsessiontick.t ........... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslsigalgs.t ............... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslsignature.t ............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslskewith0p.t ............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslversions.t .............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_sslvertol.t ................ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13alerts.t .............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13cookie.t .............. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13downgrade.t ........... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13hrr.t ................. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13kexmodes.t ............ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13messages.t ............ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13psk.t ................. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_tlsextms.t ................. Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
    No subtests run
    test\recipes\70-test_verify_extra.t ............. ok
    test\recipes\70-test_wpacket.t .................. skipped: Test disabled in this configuration
    test\recipes\80-test_ca.t ....................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_cipherbytes.t .............. ok
    test\recipes\80-test_cipherlist.t ............... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_ciphername.t ............... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_cms.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_cmsapi.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_ct.t ....................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_dane.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_dtls.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_dtls_mtu.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\80-test_dtlsv1listen.t ............. ok
    test\recipes\80-test_ocsp.t ..................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_pkcs12.t ................... skipped: Non-Greek system locale
    test\recipes\80-test_ssl_new.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\80-test_ssl_old.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\80-test_ssl_test_ctx.t ............. ok
    test\recipes\80-test_sslcorrupt.t ............... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_tsa.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\80-test_x509aux.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_asn1_time.t ................ ok
    test\recipes\90-test_async.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_bio_enc.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_bio_memleak.t .............. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_constant_time.t ............ ok
    test\recipes\90-test_fatalerr.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_gmdiff.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_gost.t ..................... skipped: No test GOST engine found
    test\recipes\90-test_ige.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_includes.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_memleak.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_overhead.t ................. skipped: Only supported in no-shared builds
    test\recipes\90-test_secmem.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_shlibload.t ................ ok
    test\recipes\90-test_srp.t ...................... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_sslapi.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_sslbuffers.t ............... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_store.t .................... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_sysdefault.t ............... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_threads.t .................. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_time_offset.t .............. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_tls13ccs.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_tls13encryption.t .......... ok
    test\recipes\90-test_tls13secrets.t ............. ok
    test\recipes\90-test_v3name.t ................... ok
    test\recipes\95-test_external_boringssl.t ....... skipped: No external tests in this configuration
    test\recipes\95-test_external_krb5.t ............ skipped: No external tests in this configuration
    test\recipes\95-test_external_pyca.t ............ skipped: No external tests in this configuration
    test\recipes\99-test_ecstress.t ................. ok
    test\recipes\99-test_fuzz.t ..................... ok

    Test Summary Report
    -------------------
    test\recipes\70-test_comp.t                   (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_key_share.t              (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_renegotiation.t          (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslcbcpadding.t          (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslcertstatus.t          (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslextension.t           (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslmessages.t            (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslrecords.t             (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslsessiontick.t         (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslsigalgs.t             (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslsignature.t           (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslskewith0p.t           (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslversions.t            (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_sslvertol.t              (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13alerts.t            (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13cookie.t            (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13downgrade.t         (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13hrr.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13kexmodes.t          (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13messages.t          (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tls13psk.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    test\recipes\70-test_tlsextms.t               (Wstat: 256 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero exit status: 1
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    Files=155, Tests=1179, 317 wallclock secs ( 1.12 usr +  0.48 sys =  1.61 CPU)
    Result: FAIL
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe' : codice restituito '0x1'
    Stop.
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : codice restituito '0x2'
    Stop.
```

Anyone know how to remove these two errors?

Comment: See also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRy3AMHVWKg) youtube video

Comment: To save you time, it is important to note that the problem is not specifically about Perl. `perl` here is used to run the test suite. I tests fail, `perl` exits with a failure code. What matters is why those tests failed. Do the failures indicate a problem with the library or do they indicate a problem with the tests? That requires an examination of the tests and why they failed to run at all (as indicated by the `0x256` exit code and the reported 0 out of 0 failures in those tests).

Comment: Didn't you get any other errors before that? On linux, make fails with an error 'openssl/des_old.h: No such file or directory' when I set the options to include old ciphers and default security level 0. This is when it is building the tests, after the actual openssl libraries and app have been built.[I know what some people will say, but I need those insecure settings to support an old device on its own dedicated network.]